# How to optimize Floor Meshes with different material in unity

Tags: unity, c#, optimization, mesh, batching

I have several meshes (floor tiles) that consist of unique materials as they have different textures. I see that it is taking too many batches and it has around 100m vertexes.

Is there any way to improve it through programming? The long way, it should be ported to 3d modeling and combine.

I also see the mesh combine but it requires the same material.

Edit:

1. Around 17k Floor tiles (LoD 9) with details
2. around 5 or 6 large tiles (Floor LoD 7) with fewer details that are placed beneath the LoD 9 tiles
3. lod9 tiles are display-based camera culling otherwise LoD7 floor shows all the time.

Here are some of the screenshots:
Lod 7 Tile example (there total 16 tiles)
[image]

Comment: Can you show us an example of the visual look you want to achieve? There may be more efficient ways we can achieve that specific outcome.

Comment: This is real-world data like satellite imagery

Comment: Ahh, that will likely have its own distinct techniques. Can you edit your question to walk us through how your scene is set up currently? How many distinct tiles do you have, and how are you currently handling levels of detail for more distant tiles?

Comment: We have some limited tiles for the lowest details floor while the highger detail tiles are appearing with camera culling system.

Comment: I did not ask for a brief one-sentence summary in a comment, I asked you to **edit your question** to walk us through your setup in detail, with specific numbers.

Comment: I have updated the question.